# Exclude nodes from package with filevault-package-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, aem

I have a content package with nodes that I would like to exclude under `/content/myApp/home` in an AEM 6.5 project. For some reason the `exclude` is not being picked up, and the content is being added to the jcr. I am building with `mvn clean install -PautoInstallPackage` and the AEM project was built with the AEM archetype.

Here's my package's `META-INF/vault/filter.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
    <filter root="/conf/myApp" mode="merge"/>
    <filter root="/content/myApp">
        <exclude pattern="/content/myApp/home"/>
    </filter>
    <filter root="/content/dam/myApp" mode="merge"/>
    <filter root="/content/experience-fragments/myApp" mode="update"/>
</workspaceFilter>
```

Here is how `filevault-package-maven-plugin` is defined in my `ui.content/pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
    <artifactId>filevault-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <allowIndexDefinitions>true</allowIndexDefinitions>
        <group>myApp</group>
        <name>myApp.ui.content</name>
        <packageType>content</packageType>
        <accessControlHandling>merge</accessControlHandling>
        <properties>
            <cloudManagerTarget>none</cloudManagerTarget>>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>myApp</groupId>
                <artifactId>myApp.ui.apps</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <subPackages>
            <subPackage>
                <groupId>com.adobe.acs</groupId>
                <artifactId>acs-aem-commons-content</artifactId>
                <filter>true</filter>
            </subPackage>
        </subPackages>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Here is how the parent pom declares `filevault-package-maven-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
  <artifactId>filevault-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.3</version>
  <configuration>
    <filterSource>src/main/content/META-INF/vault/filter.xml</filterSource>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The `filter.xml` lives under the `src/main/content/META-INF/vault` path.

After I build, I see nodes living under `/content/myApp/home`, which I do not want.

Comment: First of all - you need to check your package in `/crx/packmgr`. There you will have `Coverage` option for your package and you will check which elements are impacted. Moreover, you need to make sure that your filter is correct there. I highly recommend you to check that up, because the answer below it's "correct" but that kind of filter (assuming regex is alright) should work anyway, because Jackrabbit Vault filter picks nodes one after another, so if home node is excluded, no other nodes below this one would be even tested against filter.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the documentation my best guess is that your *exclude pattern* is not correct.

The [documentation](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/filevault/filter.html) states:

> The include and exclude elements can be added as optional children to
>   the filter element to allow more fine grained filtering of the subtree
>   during import and export. They have a mandatory pattern attribute
>   which has the format of a **regexp**. The regexp is matched against the
>   full path of the respective or potential JCR node, so it either must
>   start with / (absolute regex) or a wildcard (relative regex).

Your filter at the moment does not look like the required **regexp** expression:

```
<exclude pattern="/content/myApp/home"/>
```

Can you please try the following *exclude pattern*:

```
<exclude pattern="/content/myApp/home(.*)"/>
```

Note the `(.*)` at the end of the pattern. Also note, that this would include folders like `/content/myApp/home-automation`. So for your desired outcome you might have to change the pattern a bit more.

Comment: That's not a regular expression. Regex would be `/content/myApp/home(.*)`.

Comment: @DawidPura Thank you for the feedback. I have updated my answer. I guess the down vote is yours: please remember this [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/) by SO before doing something like this the next time. Your intentions are probably good, but the signal you are sending might be bad.

Comment: You're correct, that's something I shouldn't do. Apologize.